# Kendo UI - Upload Button - Custom

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, css, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo for the first time.

I'm using the Kendo Upload button:

```
                   @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
                            .Name("attachments")
                            .Async(async => async
                            .Save("UploadFiles", "Activity")

                            )
                    )
```

Does anyone know how to replace the standard "Select Files..." text with their own custom message.
An even better solution for me would be able to replace the content of the message with the following empty span:

```
<span class="icon-attachment">
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: About the messages, you can access `UploadMessagesBuilder` by `.Messages(m => ...)` and you can configure all sorts of labels there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At work we've been using Kendo all over the place recently. As mentioned by Patryk, the way in which Telerik expect you to amend a lot of their controls is using lambda expressions.

For what you want to do, I'd recommend the following:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
   .Name("attachments")
   .Messages( m => m.Select("Here is my custom message"))
   .Async(async => 
       async.Save("UploadFiles", "Activity")
   )
)
```